Base coat wipe dried when i got to second headlight. And didnt wait for base coat to dry before applying sealing
I used the turtlewax headlight restoration to clean headlights. I watched a video instead of instructions and did one headlight at a time so by the time I got to the second headlight the base coat dried out and the lens sealer dried just a little. Both lights look shinier but I also didn't wait for the base coat to dry before the sealant. Are these major issues?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Why not do them again, but follow the instructions? Aside: is 'manor' supposed to be 'major' or 'minor'?

Manor is supposed to mean major

You can always edit your own question.
